# How do i get the Apple from the span when the radio button is checked? Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the text in span when the radio button is checked.

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" value = 0 class="option-input radio"><span id="answer0">Apple</span></input>
```

My Jquery:

```
var answer = ($('input[name="choice"]:checked').val());
```

Comment: Hi, put the HTML code.

Comment: where's your html fragment?

Comment: sorry! i have just edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var answer = $('input[name="choice"]:checked + span').text();
```

Comment: Also you may change your HTML code to remove `</input>` in the end, since `<input>` element cannot have a child.

Comment: No problem, remember the `+` element means the element that comes next the previous element, so the selector says: give me the `span` elements that come just next all the `input` elements which have the `name` set to `'choice'` and are `checked`.